# Table on RDLC ReportViewer populated all rows values with first rows values of a Data Base

Tags: c#

I have two `Data Sets`names `Customer`and `InstallmentPaymentHistory` and two `Data Sources` `CustomerInsttDataSet` and `insttDataGridData`. `Reportviewer` takes input from a `text box`. `Table` on ReportViewer  is filled with `Database` but it show `first` `row` values filled for`all rows`

My `code` is

```
private void txtSID_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
   {            
      string sid = "";
      int isid = 0;
      id = txtSID.Text.ToString();
      if (int.TryParse(sid, out isid)) ;

      this.CustomerTableAdapter.Fill(this.CustomerInsttDataSet.Customer, isid);            
      this.installmentPaymentHistoryTableAdapter.Fill(this.insttDataGridData.InstallmentPaymentHistory, isid);
             
      this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
   }

}
```

[RDLC ReportViewer repeat first row values for all rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIKs4.gif)

Please modify my code so that `table` on `ReportViewer` populted with all `database rows`instead of repeating just `first row value`

Comment: Check you query.  It is only returning one customer 
 : this.CustomerInsttDataSet.Customer

Comment: Table is populated with insttDataGridData.InstallmentPaymentHistory and my quey in Query Builder produces required result